# PHP. JQuery. Проверка на пустое значение поля

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть функция навешенная на кнопку:

```
$('.form_id_'+formID).find("input[type='submit']").click();
```

Есть способ проверки на пустое значение:

```
            if ($("[name='REGISTER[LOGIN]']").val() != '') $('#errIdLOGIN').hide();
            if ($("[name='REGISTER[PASSWORD]']").val() != '') $('#errIdPASSWORD').hide();
            if ($("[name='REGISTER[CONFIRM_PASSWORD]']").val() != '') $('#errIdCONFIRM_PASSWORD').hide();
            if ($("[name='REGISTER[EMAIL]']").val() != '') $('#errIdEMAIL').hide();
```

Как записать общее условие при котором выполнялась бы проверка полей, если она прошла, то кнопка могла бы нажаться. Помогите с Jquery у меня беда((

Comment: Напишите без jQuery. Сейчас даже "модно" от него отказываться. В чем именно проблема?

Comment: @tutankhamun да вся форма сделана на нем, переделывать долго будет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('.form_id_2').on("submit", function(e){
 var valid = true;
 $("[name*='REGISTER']").each(function(m){
   var _this = $(this);
    if(_this.val() != ''){
     var hide_error_id = "#"+_this.attr("rel_err");
     $(hide_error_id).hide();
      console.log("hre")
    }else{
     valid = false;
    }
  })
 if(!valid){
   return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form_id_2" action="/">
  <input type="text" name="REGISTER[LOGIN]" rel_err="errIdLOGIN">
  <input type="text" name="REGISTER[PASSWORD]" rel_err="errIdPASSWORD">
  <input type="text" rel_err="errIdCONFIRM_PASSWORD" name="REGISTER[CONFIRM_PASSWORD]">
  <input type="text" rel_err="errIdEMAIL" name="REGISTER[EMAIL]">
  <input type="submit" value="Button">
  <div id="errIdLOGIN">errIdLOGIN</div>
  <div id="errIdPASSWORD">errIdPASSWORD</div>
  <div id="errIdCONFIRM_PASSWORD">errIdCONFIRM_PASSWORD</div>
  <div id="errIdEMAIL">errIdEMAIL</div>
</form>
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.form_id_'+formID).find("input[type='submit']").click();
```

Это не функция, навешенная на кнопку, это вызов события click.

Из вопроса можно только догадываться что нужно (комментарии к вопросам не могу писать пока). Как я понял нужна валидация формы перед отправкой.

```
//Если у Вас много форм и их нужно валидировать, то советую навесить на них общий класс,
//тогда можно переписать так $('.validate_form').find('input[type="submit"]')
$('.form_id_'+formID).find('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
    var submitElem = $(this),
        isValidate = true,
        form = submitElem.paretns('form');

    form.find('[name^="REGISTER"]').each(function(i, formElem){
        var formElemName = $(formElem).attr('name'),
            //Надо получить имя поля, чтобы высветить нужную ошибку, не совсем удобно получается
            fieldName = formElemName.replace(/^REGISTER\[/, '').replace(/\]$/, '');

        $('#errId' + fieldName).hide();
        if ($(formElem).val() === '') {
            isValidate = false;
            $('#errId' + fieldName).show();
        } 
    });

    if (!isValidate) {
        //валидация не прошла, 
        //тут можно вывести предупреждение или подсветить нужные элементы формы
        return false;
    }
});
```

P.S. Когда пишите выборку jq по атрибутам, то указывайте имя атрибута в двойных кавычках (как в html), а всю строку выборки, соответственно, в одинарных.

Comment: вы правильно поняли, если вам интересно то я могу показать полностью скрипт...сложноват конечно на понимание, сам кое как вникаю в него.

Comment: Так вроде Oleksandr и я уже написали скрипты для валидации. Нужное что-то еще?